# Не выполняется условие задачи через алгоритм

Tags: c++, алгоритм

По условию задачи необходимо добавить к каждому числу в векторе среднее наименьшего и наибольшего по абсолютной величине.
вот main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <climits>
#include "Function.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    vector <int> num;
    vector <int> num_;

    ofstream in ("output.txt");
    input(in);
    in.close();
    ifstream out("output.txt");
    num = inputfile(out);
    out.close();
    copy(num.begin(), num.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    summ(num);
    num_ = modify(num);
    cout << endl;

    for_each(num_.begin(), num_.end(),
    [] (int x) {cout << setw(3) << x;});

    return 0;
}
```

и хедер для него. Программа запускается, но условие не выполняется. В чем ошибка понять не могу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void input (ofstream &in) {
    vector <int> vi;
    generate_n (back_inserter (vi), 100,
                [] {return rand() % 101 - 50;});
    transform(vi.begin(),vi.end(),
              ostream_iterator<int>(in, " "),
              [] (int x) {return x;});

}

vector <int> inputfile(ifstream & out) {
    vector <int> vi;
    transform(istream_iterator<int>(out),istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(vi),
            [] (int x) {return x;});
    return vi;
}

int summ(vector<int> vi){

    int sum = accumulate(vi.begin(),vi.end(),0);
    cout << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}

vector <int> modify(vector <int> &other){

    vector<int> vi;

//    std::cout << "Min. element on modul = " << *std::min_element(vi.cbegin(), vi.cend(), [](const auto x, const auto y)
//    {return std::abs(x) < std::abs(y); });
//
//    std::cout << "\nThe largest element is "  << *std::max_element(vi.begin(),vi.begin()+50) << "\n";

    int minim = *std::min_element(vi.cbegin(), vi.cend(), [](const auto x, const auto y)
    {return std::abs(x) < std::abs(y); });

    int maxi = *std::max_element(vi.begin(),vi.begin()+50);

    int summa = (minim+maxi)/2;
    cout<<"arithmetic mean is"<<summa<<endl;

    transform(other.begin(), other.end(), back_inserter(vi),
            [&summa] (int x) {return x += summa;});
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Какое условие не выполняется то? Может ответ не соответствует ответу в задаче? Тогда приведите входные данные, ожидаемый ответ и получаемый ответ.

Comment: @VTT добавить к каждому числу в векторе среднее наименьшего и наибольшего по абсолютной величине

Comment: @VTT входные данные приведены, ожидаемый ответ - выполнение условия, получаемый ответ - на экран выводится просто сгенерированная последовательность чисел, заполняющих вектор. А по условию к каждому этому числу нужно прибавить среднее среднее наименьшего и наибольшего по абсолютной величине. Все это должно быть записано в файл.

Comment: Где приведены входные данные? Вижу только исходный код.

Comment: @Komdosh в исходном коде и приведены, в хедере создается вектор, заполненный случайными числами от -50 до +50. Нужно работать с этим вектором.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что входные данные сначала рандомно генерируются, записываются в файл `"output.txt"`, потом читаются из этого файла. Вам наверное стоит выбрать конкретный набор входных данных, причем самый маленький, и привести его и результат обработки

Comment: Ну вот у вас получается странно, @VTT говорит правильные вещи

Comment: Дополнительно 2. Проверьте значение minim и maxi, будет понятно правильно ли найден минимум и максимум. 3. У вас отсутствует модуль (*по абсолютной величине*) в формулах.

Comment: @VTT Да, все верно. Но в задачнике нужно именно так делать, создавать вектор с числами, записать его в файл и с ним работать, это не моя прихоть, тут ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: @nick_n_a 2. проверяла, они верны. 3. этим пренебрегла, это не самое важное в задаче. Меня беспокоит vector <int> modify(vector <int> &other){...}. Кажется, что проблема в нем, но не понимаю, где

Comment: Да, однако после генерации вектора его можно не вычитывать из файла. А для воспроизводимости результатов, для отладки и для вопроса на SO имеет смысл выбрать конкретный набор исходных данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a по абсолютной величине значения найдены верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что пихать *реализацию* в заголовочный файл, гм... альтернативненько как-то.

Далее. У вас конкретно

> По условию задачи необходимо добавить к каждому числу в векторе среднее наименьшего и наибольшего по абсолютной величине

Т.е. нужна функция, которая модифицирует сам вектор, добавляя к элементам... не то |min|+|max|/2, не то |min+max|/2.

Ну так давайте ее и [напишем](https://ideone.com/npqZDW).

```
void solution(vector<int>&v) // Меняем сам вектор
{
    if(v.empty()) return;

    // Ищем min/max
    auto [m,M] = minmax_element(v.begin(),v.end());

    // Прибавляем **нужное** среднее
    int d = abs(*m+*M)/2;  // (abs(*m)+abs(*M))/2
    for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[d](int&x){ x+= d; });
}
```

Собственно, все. Все через алгоритмы. Все остальное - это совершенно другие вопросы...

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Но компилятор выдает ошибку : error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token|  в строчке auto [m,M] = minmax_element(v.begin(),v.end());

Comment: Компилятор не самый свежий. Гляньте по [ссылке в ответе](https://ideone.com/npqZDW) - там вариант для более старого компилятора...

Answer (score 1):

```
vector <int> modify(vector <int> &other){

    vector<int> vi;
```

вы обьявляете новый пустой обьект, а потом обращаетесь к его элементам. Ваш заполненный обьект, это `other`, а не `vi`

```
//    std::cout << "Min. element on modul = " << *std::min_element(vi.cbegin(), vi.cend(), [](const auto x, const auto y)
//    {return std::abs(x) < std::abs(y); });
//
//    std::cout << "\nThe largest element is "  << *std::max_element(vi.begin(),vi.begin()+50) << "\n";
```

//...

Во превых все это ерунда, поскольку ваш `vi` пустой вектор, и вы должны все это проделать с вектором `other`

Во вторых, вы используете альгоритмы не по предназначению

В третьих для этой простой задачи нужны всего один контейнер и один альгоритм(всего две строчки кода)

Вот ваша программа:

```
 void my_code(vector<int>& v)
{   
    auto first = v.begin(), last = v.end();
    const int  k = (abs(*std::min_element(first, last))
            + abs(*std::max_element(first, last))) /2;
    std::transform(first, last, first, [&](int x) { return x + k; });
    std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: vi не пустой вектор, он заполнен случайными числами. Вот дополненное условие задачи: "Написать функцию, с помощью которой подготовить текстовый файл input.txt, сохранив в него 100 случайных целых чисел в диапазоне от -50 до 50 по одному на строке.
Файл возвращается функцией как результат. Написать функцию inputfile(), получающую файл как аргумент и возвращающий последовательный контейнер, заполненный числами
из файла.

Comment: Написать функцию modify(), получающую в качестве аргумента контейнер-результат функции inputfile(). Модифицированный контейнер возвращается в качестве результата. Добавить контейнер-результат вычисление суммы и среднего арифметического по абсолютной величине. В качестве контейнера использовать вектор."

Comment: Если вы обьявили вектор в одной функции, то это не значит, что обьявленный вектор с тем же именем в другой функции будет тем же самим вектором. Это лишь временные обьекты, которые уничтожаются  сразу после вызова функции

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему, "наименьшего и наибольшего по абсолютной величине" означает, что надо искать с меньшим модулем элемент и с большим. Для этого нужно добавить функтор в поиск минимаксимума -

```
auto m = minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
                        [](int a, int b) {
                        return a * a < b * b;});
int d = (*m.first + *m.second) / 2;
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), 
         [d](int& x) {x += d;});
```